Insert current date Cmd/Ctrl + semicolon
I remember I was using shortcut to insert current date in open office, but it seems it is not working right now.
In Google Spreadsheet I can still use ⌘ Cmd + ; for current date and ⌘ Cmd + Shift + ; for current time.
In OpenOffice on OS X none of these shortcuts are working now.
How to fix this? Or is there any other shortcut?

You can bind those functions to any key combination yourself:

go to Tools -> Customize... -> Keyboard
choose some key combination
assign Insert -> Date to one and Insert -> Time to another one

